# Must glUniform/glVertexAttribPointer type match declared type in shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

To what extent must types match between GLSL code and native code that passes data?

For example, suppose I have shader code:

```
uniform float uFloat;
uniform int uInt;
in float aFloat;
in int aInt;
```

and native **pseudocode** (I'm leaving out lots of boring stuff):

```
glUniform1i(glUniformLocation("uFloat"), 10)
glUniform1f(glUniformLocation("uInt"), 1.414)
glBufferData(int[1, 2, 3, ...])
glVertexAttribPointer(glAttribLocation("aFloat"), 0, GL_INT)
glBufferData(float[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, ...])
glVertexAttribPointer(glAttribLocation("aInt"), 0, GL_FLOAT)
```

So notice types match within the client code, but they don't match up with declared types in shader code.

What I'm asking is, are you telling the shader values at a logical level, or in terms of bit representation?

(I know it seems I should be able to just test this, but it's hard to debug shaders and I feel like I'm having inconsistent behavior, so I'm just looking for definitive info.)

Comment: I hope this does not confuse you, but there is one more case here you have not considered: *opaque data types*. These include things like *samplers*, *images* and *atomic counters*; they are not really integers, but rather identifying handles. `sampler2D` is considered a floating-point opaque type (because the sampled texture is floating-point), but you still communicate the handle's value (texture image unit) using `glUniform1i (...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `type` parameter to `glVertexAttribPointer` specifies the type of the data *inside of the buffer*. If it's an integer type, the values are automatically converted to floating point values by the GPU when the vertex is being read, either by converting them straight to floating-point values if `normalized` is `GL_FALSE`, or by dividing them by the maximum value of the integer type if `normalized` is `GL_TRUE`.

However, `glVertexAttribPointer` only works with `in float` inputs (even if you pass an integer buffer type), but on your last line, you are using it with an `in int`. For that, you must use `glVertexAttribIPointer` (note the `I`). While it has a `type` parameter, it does not accept floating-point formats like `GL_FLOAT`; you cannot pass in a buffer of floating-point values to an integer vertex attribute.

(There is also `glVertexAttribLPointer` for `double`s, but those aren't frequently used.)

Uniforms are more strict; you must use the appropriate `glUniform` function for the type you're using (ex. `glUniform1i` for `int` types and `glUniform1f` for `float` types), otherwise you get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! The glUniform* functions don't return a result. I guess I should be calling glGetError after each call?

Comment: @Grumdrig Most OpenGL functions don't return their error codes; they instead set some variable that you can retrieve with `glGetError`. Alternatively, you can use the `KHR_debug` extension if your GPU supports it; that lets you pass in a callback function, which is passed a much more descriptive error message.